# Access variable of outer function from inner function

Tags: python

I want to use a construct like this, where a function is defined inside of another and can alter a value defined in the outer function:

```
def function1():
    res = []
    def function2():
        global res
        if (possibleToAnswer):
            res.append(answer)
        else:
            function2()
    return res
print (("%s") % function1(para))
```

It doesn't seem to work. I keep getting unbound bug. Any idea about how to get it to work?

Comment: What is this trying to accomplish?

Comment: You don't want `global`. Also, your example isn't complete and verifiable because certain parts (e.g. `possibleToAnswer`) aren't defined in what you've posted.

Comment: Also—you don't define `function1` as accepting any parameters, yet you call it the parameter `para`.

Comment: Is your question addressed? If so, you can help future users by marking the checkbox beside the correct answer. If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `global`—it's not in the immediate scope of `function2`, but it's not *global*.

```
def function1():
    res = []
    def function2():
        if (possibleToAnswer):
            res.append(answer)
        else:
            function2()
    return res
print (("%s") % function1(para))
```

Comment: so all i have to do is just using it without "global''?

Comment: It's impossible for us to answer that until you provide a Minimal, complete, and verifiable example.